# Ant and File.isDirectory()

Tags: java, ant

I have a test run via `ant` which includes a component that checks to make sure a path provided as an argument is a directory, using:

```
 File dir = new File(path);
 if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
      System.err.println("Invalid directory "+path+".");
```

When run via the ant task:

```
    <java
        classname="foo.bar"
        classpath="${classpath}"
    >
        <arg value="-d ${testDir}"/>
```

Where `testDir` is a location property containing a relative path, the component fails with the "Invalid directory" message reflecting the *absolute* (but correct) path.

When run directly from the same location sans ant, using `java -cp[yada] foo.bar -d /the/exact/same/absolute/path`, there is no such problem.

I am quite new to ant and presume there is [some permission I have to grant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/permissions.html) here?

Note that:

- `${testDir}` is a subdirectory, i.e., it does not lead up out of the project tree.
- The absolute path of `${testDir}` and all the components therein are **world readable**.

Answer (score 1):

If `testDir` is a relative path, it will be resolved using system property **user.dir** by default. A quick solution is run `ant` in parent dir.

You can also add `dir` to specify current directory when *java task* running.

```
<java
    classname="foo.bar"
    classpath="${classpath}"
    dir="${parentDir}"
    fork="true"
>
    <arg value="-d ${testDir}"/>
```

The attribute `fork="true"` is required if you get following message:

> [java] Working directory ignored when same JVM is used.

Comment: *"If testDir is a relative path, it will be resolved using system property user.dir by default."* -> As stated explicitly in the question, that's exactly what's happening, and what I want. The directory reported by the application is resolved to *"the absolute **(but correct)** path"* and if I **literally cut n' paste it** into `java [...] /the/exact/same/absolute/path` it's fine.  I  realize using `fork` may get me out of this -- but it also creates more restrictions than it is worth.  At that point, I might as well run the test from a  one line shell wrapper -- ant serves no purpose at all.

Comment: To clarify the point further, if I replace `${testDir}` with the literal and absolute path, I get the same result.  Further, it happens in both cases *with* `fork=true`.   The only thing fork saves me is having to read `org.apache.tools.ant.ExitException: Permission ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") was not granted` (because it bails on `is.Directory()` failing) -- which is what turned me on to the whole concept of ant permissions, and why I would presume this has something to do with that.  The component has the correct path, it just is not allowed to read it...or something.

Comment: How does your `main` method handle the argument `-d ${testDir}` and set it to variable `path`? During my testing, if my program want to get `${testDir}` without modify input variable, I have to specify `<arg value="-d"/><arg value="${testDir}"/>` in build.xml.

Comment: I'm using a (wrapper on) [apache commons cli](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/).  If you look at the [first example here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg), you'll see that `<arg value="-d foo">` counts as one argument, which is what it is.  But that is not what is happening, so there's either a bug in ant or the documentation is incorrect, which amounts to the same thing (see the explanation in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed something interesting looking more closely at the output.  The project directory is `/home/devel/project/` (but note `/home/devel` is not a normal home directory; `devel` is just a group and that directory is world *readable*, and also writable by the executing user). The `${testDir}` is (again) a relative path, `test/serverconf`, which ant then correctly resolves to `/home/devel/project/test/serverconf.

But here's what I noticed in the error from the component:

```
Invalid directory  /home/devel/project/test/serverconf.
                 ^^
```

There are *two* spaces there, whereas the error message itself only produces one.  If I try to run the application `java foo.bar.Server -d " /home/devel/project/test/serverconf"`, of course I get the same error. It's not looking for an absolute path in this case, it's looking for a relative one starting with a space character (if I'd used quotes on the bad arg in the error message, this would have been clear).

However, **this is an ant bug** in the sense that it [explicitly contradicts the documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg), which clearly states under "Examples":

> `<arg value="-l -a"/>`
>
> is a single command-line argument containing a space character, not separate commands "-l" and "-a".

In the `build.xml`, there is only one space in `-d ${testDir}`.  I tried `-d${testdir}`, since the command line parser (org.apache.commons.cli) will accept it either way.  What it will choke on is `-d " /whatever/path"`.

So ant is resolving `${testDir}`, then passing *two* arguments in, `"-d"`, and `" /home/devel/project..."`.  If this were then just a subtlety of how ant substitutes variables, I would say okay, "bug-like" but since there's a potential caveat which provides an exception to the documented example, it's just a gotcha.

**But** using the literal path instead of a variable:

```
<arg value="-d test/serverconf">
```

Leads to the same issue:

```
Invalid directory  test/serverconf
                 ^^
```

And to be clear again, the relative path will work fine here when `java foo.bar.Server` is run from the same directory as `ant target`.  But not if used `-d " test/serverconf"`, because the user should be allowed to use quotes and include spaces that way.

**So the statement about `arg value` in the documentation is false.**  Ant is *not* passing it through as "a single command-line argument containing a space".  It is passing it through as *two* arguments and including the space in the second one.

Go figure.